# IIS rewrite module terminology

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm just trying to understand IIS rewrite module terminology.

[image]

(i.)What is difference between  url and  {Url} as highlighted above ?

(ii.) Suppose, if we have multiple conditions like above, So {C:0} or {C:1}  will refer from QUERY_STRING or  HTTP_HOST or URL ?
      I mean to say , how to get conditional reference fr QUERY_STRING and HTTP_HOST and URL so that i can use them in action ?

Please let me know if anything not clear.

Thanks

Comment: If you carefully design a few experiments, the meanings can be easily identified. Then you can ask your own question.

Comment: @Lex li:   I  have doubts fr my second query. if thr is only one condition thn i can understand meanings of {C:0} and {C:1}...But if thr are multiple condtions like above thn not sure {C:0} and {C:1} will refer to which conditions ? hope u getting me.